# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'data' (TENSORFLOW, KERAS)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

I am pretty new to Deep Learning and I was trying to make my first ANN which implements a XOR gate

I am using anaconda. I checked which packages I've got installed in my base environment and tensorflow and keras are up to date.
Everything goes well until I fit my model, that's when I get the attribute error I wrote as the title of the post

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers


#XOR training data
training = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], "float32")
#target or output desired values
target = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]], "float32")

# CREATION OF THE MODEL
nn = keras.models.Sequential()
#Input layer: 2 neurons
#Hidden layer: 16 neurons
#Output layer: 1 value 
nn.add(layers.Dense(16, input_dim = 2, activation = 'relu'))
nn.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

nn.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])


# TRAINING THE MODEL (When executing this sentence, the error appears)
nn.fit(training, target, epochs = 1000)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you're importing `Sequential` like that you don't need `keras.models.` before it in your code.

Comment: could you add the full error trace back to the body of your post please

Comment: Please do not add errors as images, only as text.

Comment: As it is stated in the comment this `nn = Sequential()` doesn't show any error

Comment: Add 'tf' to `nn =tf.keras.models.Sequential()` and try again executing the same code.